# Problem with background-position with px in Firefox 4

Tags: css, firefox, firefox4, background-position

I'm positioning a background sprite and changing the position on hover (using jQuery), and it works as expected in Chrome, IE(8) and Safari (I'm on a PC, Win 7) but I'm having problems with Firefox (4). Nothing happens and in the error console I get this:

> Warning: Error in parsing value for 'background-position'.  Declaration dropped.

I initially position the background like this:

```
background-position: bottom left;
```

and alter the position on hover like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var bgPos = 'bottom left';

        $("#nav-01").hover(function () { $('.nav-wrap').css('background-position', '-787px left'); }, function () { $('.nav-wrap').css('background-position', bgPos); });
        $("#nav-02").hover(function () { $('.nav-wrap').css('background-position', '-656px left'); }, function () { $('.nav-wrap').css('background-position', bgPos); });
        $("#nav-03").hover(function () { $('.nav-wrap').css('background-position', '-525px left'); }, function () { $('.nav-wrap').css('background-position', bgPos); });
        $("#nav-04").hover(function () { $('.nav-wrap').css('background-position', '-394px left'); }, function () { $('.nav-wrap').css('background-position', bgPos); });
        $("#nav-05").hover(function () { $('.nav-wrap').css('background-position', '-263px left'); }, function () { $('.nav-wrap').css('background-position', bgPos); });
        $("#nav-06").hover(function () { $('.nav-wrap').css('background-position', '-132px left'); }, function () { $('.nav-wrap').css('background-position', bgPos); });
        $("#nav-07").hover(function () { $('.nav-wrap').css('background-position', '-1px left'); }, function () { $('.nav-wrap').css('background-position', bgPos); });

    });
```

To debug I tried changing **'-787px left'** to **'top left'** and that worked, so the problem seems to be positioning the background using px in Firefox? Is this a bug (a feature... hehe) or am I simply doing something wrong...? (I also tried using em and % but none of it worked.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-787px` is a perfectly valid value for `background-position`. However, you are mixing the order: Horizontal comes first. That could be the problem. Try turning the values around:

```
left -787px
```

Comment: Thank you, I was just going to reply to my own question stating exactly that. A bit embarrassing but hopefully it'll help someone in the future ... ;)

Comment: Another note - in CSS2 mixed values for positioning were not allowed. This got fixed with CSS2.1